# Pothos(?) water propagated too long

Tags: houseplants

These cuttings (which I was told is a Pothos) had been water propagated too long, I think, and now the roots are very very long (almost 3x the length of the plant itself).
I inherited these plants recently and am wondering if it's too late to transfer to soil. I am quite new to houseplants, but did read that water roots and soil roots are different. Will I kill the plant if I try to transfer it to soil now?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Pothos, I think]

Answer (score 1):

Just trim the roots back until you easily plant them in soil.  The key to success here is allowing time for the water roots to develop the fine root hairs they need in soil.

Pothos is extremely tough and many people will have success just planting it.  If possible you could raise the humidity for a few days by putting a transparent plastic bag or glass globe over the pot.  Don't leave it on too long or the lack of air circulation will promote mold and fungus.

Light should be strong but indirect but while it's rooting don't put it up against a south window where it could get too much light.

Once established this plant is almost unkillable. It will try and climb and in a moist environment will put out roots at every node which can stick to most surfaces as it is a climber in it's natural environment

[image: Epipremnum aureum]
Courtesy of wikimedia.org